# Usage of bitwise shifting

Tags: python, binary, bit-shift

I can understand quite well how bit shifting works, but I can't find any situation where I can use it for faster/better result.
Could someone explain when it's useful to use operators `>>` and `<<`?

```
x = 2
y = 7
z = 16

a = x << y
print(bin(x), "with %d zeros removed from left/added on right ->" % y, bin(a))

b = z >> x
print(bin(z), "with %d zeros removed from right/added on left ->" % x, bin(b))
```

Comment: One of the use is multiplication and division by 2^n numbers.

Comment: bit shifting has applications in embedded systems where you have limited resources

Comment: `x << 4` is faster to write and easier to "parse" (by eye), than `x * 2**4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure where it will be useful in usual coding. But when it comes to embedded programming this has immense usage. To manipulate registers I used to use bit-wise operators quite often.